# How to create a "many-to-many" relationships between ApplicationUser and a Project in Blazor WebAssembly with ASP.NET Core Hosted?

Tags: c#, many-to-many, asp.net-core-webapi, blazor-server-side, blazor-webassembly

I created a Blazor WebAssembly project with ASP.NET Core Hosted. The solution consists of 3 projects:

- MyApp.Client,
- MyApp.Server and it contains:

  ```
  public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
  {
      public string FirstName { get; set; }
      public string LastName { get; set; }
      // If I uncomment AdviceDocumentsUsers then I dont get the error
      public List<AdviceDocumentsUsers> AdviceDocumentsUsers { get; set; } = new List<AdviceDocumentsUsers>();
  }

  public class AdviceDocumentsUsers
  {
      public string ApplicationUserId { get; set; }
      public ApplicationUser ApplicationUser { get; set; }
      public int AdviceDocumentId { get; set; }
      public AdviceDocument AdviceDocument { get; set; }
  }
  ```
- MyApp.Shared and it contains AdviceDocument:

  ```
  public class AdviceDocument
  {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public List<AdviceDocumentsUsersDTO> AdviceDocumentsUsersDTO { get; set; } = new List<AdviceDocumentsUsersDTO>();
  }

  public class AdviceDocumentsUsersDTO
  {
    public string ApplicationUserId { get; set; }
    public int AdviceDocumentId { get; set; }
  }

  public class UserModel<T>
  {
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public List<AdviceDocument> AdviceDocuments { get; set; }
    public List<AdviceDocumentsUsersDTO> AdviceDocumentsUsersDTO { get; set; } = new List<AdviceDocumentsUsersDTO>();
  }
  ```

MyApp.Client and MyApp.Server have MyApp.Shared as ProjectReference.

MyApp.Shared cannot get AdviceDocumentsUsers class, that is why I'm using AdviceDocumentsUsersDTO and UserModel. In the controllers I'm mapping AdviceDocumentsUsers to AdviceDocumentsUsersDTO and ApplicationUser to UserModel.

If I run and try to login, I get an error:

> InvalidOperationException: The entity type 'AdviceDocumentsUsers'
> requires a primary key to be defined. If you intended to use a keyless
> entity type, call 'HasNoKey' in 'OnModelCreating'. For more
> information on keyless entity types, see
> https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2141943.

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : ApiAuthorizationDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext(
        DbContextOptions options,
        IOptions<OperationalStoreOptions> operationalStoreOptions) : base(options, operationalStoreOptions)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.Entity<AdviceDocumentsUsers>().HasKey(x => new { x.ApplicationUserId, x.AdviceDocumentId });

        base.OnModelCreating(builder);
    }

    public DbSet<ApplicationUser> ApplicationUsers { get; set; }
    public DbSet<AdviceDocument> AdviceDocuments { get; set; }
    public DbSet<AdviceDocumentsUsers> AdviceDocumentsUsers { get; set; }
}
```

What do I need to change in order to get a proper many-to0many relationship working between ApplicationUser and AdviceDocument?

Comment: You want to keep your "Shared" project for declaring object to be passed between Client and Server.  If AdviceDocument is part of your data model then that should not be in there.  That should be in "Server".  Regarding the key error, that line you've REMmed out should be the one to tell EF what the primary key is.  Why did you REM that out?

Comment: That's my mistake, I was testing something else and forgot to uncomment that line. Thank you, I wll correct it. AdviceDocument is part of the users data. If I put it in MyApp.Server then MyApp.Client can not access the type AdviceDocument. Should I put AdviceDocument in the Server and create a new class in Shared to map AdviceDocument to it in the Client side?

Comment: Yes.  Best to keep your client away from the data model and put DTOs in the shared project.  Map between DTOs and Data Model Entities in the server.